# Fragments: Replacing a fragment causes it to reinstantiate on back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am using one activity all fragment approach. Now I have a fragment A and when I go to fragment B I replace A in container with B with

```
.replace(R.id.master_fragment_container_above_toolbar, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("")
                .commit();
```

As you can see, I have added fragment to backStack. But now when I press back on device, it re-instantiates the fragment A and thus takes time to go back.

Is there another way to do it? I don't want to use `add()`, if I add multiple fragments to container, it will take up a lot of memory.

Comment: Just a piece of advice .. avoid doing one activity all fragment approach beacuse of two reasons : 1)Stack management issues 2)When too many fragments are there - it also makes managing memory , etc tough. Better to use activity for a screen and fragment where you wish to avoid code repitition like in pager , multi part display on screen, etc

Comment: You should read more here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer - there's no silver bullet in your case. You'll have to use `replace()` and it will re-create fragment's `View` on going back. That's "by design".

The good news is that there're a few tricks you can do to make it less dramatic for UX.

- Cache whatever you can. If you load content from web - write it into the local  SQLite db. And fill the screen from Local Storage while refreshing the data from the server.
- In `onCreateView()` avoid re-creating Adapters once they are already exist. If user is getting back to FragmentA from the FragmentB, FragmentA will recreate its `View`. But it doesn't mean, that local variables are null at this point. So I do it like this:

  ```
  public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

      private  FeedAdapter adapter;

      ......

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View rootView = initialize(inflater, container, R.layout.fragment_with_recyclerview);
          ....
          if (adapter == null) {
              adapter = new FeedAdapter();
          }

          RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

          return rootView;
      }
  }
  ```

  It matters, because filling `TextView`s, etc. are so fast operations, that you don't really care about it, while huge `ListView` or `RecyclerView` can be much more expensive;
- Use image-caching and good image-loading tool. I'd recommend [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) from Square. It has automatic memory and disk caching;
- Try to logically decouple your app. Let's take a Gmail-style application, as an example:
  It has `NavigationDrawer`, which is switching user through the root fragments (i.e. no need to keep navigation stack). Once you open mail-thread - it replaces the root fragment with MailThread fragment. There you can consume the content.

  But once you click on "Compose email" - you are redirecting to a separate `Activity` - as you move from consuming content to composing content state (I.e. significant change in user's behaviour: *new user scenario == new activity*).

  Many top developers go even further and having Activities for pretty much everything. Twitter (and it's satellite products) as an example. But personally, I prefer to keep it in balance (as opening new activity is an expensive operation from perf. point of view).

Comment: Thank you so much. The points are really good and helpful. I think I should use activities here. Because my Fragment A contains a viewpager (which contains 3 fragments), so replacing it and coming back would be a very expensive operation.

Comment: Plus just wondering, how did you get the information about the navigations of Twitter and Gmail. It might be a stupid question but did you reverse engineer the code or is there a resource available?

Comment: @VipulKumar you are welcome! Actually, it's not a stupid question at all. Unfortunately, there's no magic behind: just observations. Switching activities caused black "blinking" and little lag in the UI, while switching fragments is almost immediate operations (=> it can be better animated). Plus regarding Twitter - I am a little familiar with some of their engineers (+ they give talks like this one https://vimeo.com/144678505 , where they reveal their mindset regarding architecture of apps)